# How to implement a game launch counter in LibGDX

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm writing a game using LibGDX in which I want to save the number of launches of a game in a text file.
So, In the create() of my starter class, I have the following code ..but it's not working

```
public class MainStarter extends Game {

    private int count;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        // Set up the application
        AppSettings.setUp();
        if(SettingsManager.isFirstLaunch()){
            SettingsManager.createTextFileInLocalStorage("gamedata");
            SettingsManager.writeLine("gamedata", "Launched:"+count ,FileType.LOCAL_FILE );
        }
        else{
            SettingsManager.writeLine("gamedata", "Not First launch :"+count++ ,FileType.LOCAL_FILE );
        }

        //
        // Load assets before setting the screen
        // #####################################
        Assets.loadAll();

        // Set the tests screen
        setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(this, "Main Menu"));
    }   
}
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: What exactly is wrong right now?? Also, you'll probably want to show code for createTextFileInLocalStorage and writeLine so that we can see how u r using libGDX.

Comment: Both the methods are working well for storing other variables.. I just want to store the number of times the game has been launched.

Comment: Shouldn't you be reading a value from that file into `count` when its not the first launch? Also shouldn't `count` be initialized to 1?

Comment: This seems like a general "how do I program" question, as opposed to anything related to game development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly the "SettingsManager" is, as you haven't provided any information on what it does internally. Normally for this kind of persistent data you would use [Preferences](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/Preferences) to store it in a cross-platform manner. Something like the following code in your create() method:

```
Preferences prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("My Preferences");
int count = prefs.getInteger("RunCount", 0);
count++;
prefs.putInteger("RunCount", count);
prefs.flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the count of your game launch first make a LocalPreferences class and write following

```
public class LocalPreferencees{
    Preferences prefs;

    public LocalPreferencees() {
        prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("GAMECOUNT");         
        }

     public void setCount (int count) {
        prefs.putInteger("COUNT",count);
        prefs.flush();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return prefs.getInteger("COUNT",0);
    }
}
```

then in your create() method write following

```
@Override
public void create(){

    LocalPreferences preferences=new LocalPreferences();

   //this will get your game launch count
    int count=preferences.getCount();

    //now set the count
    prferences.setCount(count+1);

}
```

So each time when your game launches you will get the launchCount .